# Which method to change to expose Business data in ewam?

Tags: ewam

I need to create a new business data which needs to be exposed and used in the Rule. I have the logic and code with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally data points are added as dynamic data and tied to your rules through configuration. However if you are adding persistent variables to the entire Wynsure implementation you will need to:

1. Create a Custom rules engine which descends from the main rules engine tied for the relevant rule category i.e. aWLIRuleEngine (for all rules) aWLIClaimRuleEngine (for claims rules)  aWLO_LoanRuleEngoine (for loan rules) and so on.
2. In the new or reimplemented rules engine add a variables to hold for each data point you want to expose. This should match the business variable in type.
3. Add a Second Boolean variable to track whether or not the the first variable has been loaded or not.
4. Create a function to retrieve the data from the Wynsure business class and copy that data to the rules engine place holder (and change the boolean to verify this had been done).
5. Override the Proc that declares all the the retrieval functions (inherit all previous versions in the parents then append your own).
6. Override your Main business object to use your custom rules engine instead of the original client.

Example: We have a city code that is used in a particular implementation of Wynsure. This project is Individual life and the client would like to make available to all the rules engines that deal with their life projects. We need to override the Rules engine class, and the individual product class:

```
; aCUS_RuleEngine (aWLIRuleEngine) (Def Version:2) (Implem Version:3)

uses CUS_Types, aWLIContract, aListOfInstances, aMethodDesc

memory Master : aCUS_RuleEngine override 
v_Subscriber__TrinCityCode : tCUS_ParishDynamicEnum
Subscriber__TrinCodeUpdated : Boolean
v_Subscriber__TriniID : CString
Subscriber__TriniIDUpdated : Boolean


function Subscriber__TriniID return CString
   uses aCUS_Person

   if self.Master <> Nil
      return self.Master.Subscriber__TriniID
   else
      if not self.Subscriber__TriniIDUpdated and not self.Test
         self.v_Subscriber__TriniID = aCUS_Person(self.ForContract.Subscriber).IDNumber
         self.Subscriber__TriniIDUpdated = True
      endIf
      return self.v_Subscriber__TriniID
   endIf
endFunc 

function Subscriber__TrinCityCode return tCUS_ParishDynamicEnum
   uses aCUS_Person

   if self.Master <> Nil
      return self.Master.Subscriber__TrinCityCode
   else
      if not self.Subscriber__TrinCodeUpdated and not self.Test
         self.v_Subscriber__TrinCityCode = aCUS_Person(self.ForContract.Subscriber).BirthParish
         self.Subscriber__TrinCodeUpdated = True
      endIf
      return self.v_Subscriber__TrinCityCode
   endIf
endFunc 

procedure DeclareSubscriberAsPersonBusinessFunctions(List : aListOfInstances) override
   inherited self.DeclareSubscriberAsPersonBusinessFunctions(List)
   List.AppendObject(MetaModelEntity(self.Subscriber__TrinCityCode))
   List.AppendObject(MetaModelEntity(self.Subscriber__TriniID))
endProc 





; aCUS_LifeIndividualProduct (aWLI_LifeIndividualProduct) (Def Version:3) (Implem Version:4)

uses aCUS_IndividualCoverage, aClassDef

Options : listOf [O] aCUS_IndividualCoverage inverse MyOwner override 


function RuleEngineClassDef return aClassDef override
   uses aCUS_RuleEngine

   _Result = MetaModelEntity(aCUS_RuleEngine)
endFunc
```